# Several questions about NDB keys

Tags: hash, key, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Question a: Is there any absolute guarantee that an entity successfully retrieved from NDB will not contain a key with value None, nor key.id() with value None? Is this guarantee written anywhere in the docs?

Question b: Do keys store the id as a str/int? Or do keys store id in a hash to be decrypted with key.id() is called? If has, proceed to question c.

Question c: Is the number of characters in the key hash limited or a set amount? If yes, proceed to question d.

Question d: When trying to create a Key, does the constructor limit the str len of its id when trying to create a Key? If no, proceed to question e.

Question e: If I construct a key with a str id of len equal to len of key hash + 1, how can the key decrypyt and retrieve the id with id() if the range of values the hash can have is less than the range of values of the str id I provide?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Answer a: If you ever retrieve an entity with a key (or id) of Null, that would indicate a much bigger problem with NDB.  As far as I know, this is not possible because every entity needs a key.  No, there's no "guarantee" of this apart from the [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python).

Answer b: The key stores the id as a str/int, as seen in the [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/key.py):

```
def id(self):
    """Return the string or integer id in the last (kind, id) pair, if any.
    Returns:
      A string or integer id, or None if the key is incomplete.
    """
    return self.__pairs[-1][1]
```

Since it does not use a hash, I did not proceed with answers c, d and e.